# How to write sub lemmas

Tags: theorems, code

I want to code like that,

Lemma 1. I will marry if,

Case (i)  I found a soul mate

Case (ii) never married

How would I code this in LaTeX, I have used `\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}`
but I dont know how to get the pointwise cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way described by @sebastian is clearly the standard way, and it will do the job in most of the cases. There is one situation I encountered several times: The cases start right after the theorem title. Here you have to hard-code an empty box, which I found not beatiful. To solve this you can do:

```
\newenvironment{enumlemma}
  {\begin{lemma}\mbox{}
  \begin{enumerate}[(i)]}
  {\end{enumerate}
  \end{lemma}}
```

To take control over the enumeration pattern and to include a environment body that *not* belongs to the case list, you can adjust it like this:

```
\newenvironment{enumlemma}[2][(i)]
  {\begin{lemma}#2\mbox{}
  \begin{enumerate}[#1]}
  {\end{enumerate}
  \end{lemma}}
```

The complete code with a small test could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newenvironment{enumlemma}[2][(i)]
  {\begin{lemma}#2\mbox{}
  \begin{enumerate}[#1]}
  {\end{enumerate}
  \end{lemma}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumlemma}[a)]
{Let $(f_n)$ be the Fibonacci sequence. Then the following equations hold.}
\item $f_{2n+1}=f_n^2+f_{n+1}^2$.
\item $f_{n+1}f_{n-1}-f_n^2=(-1)^n$.
\end{enumlemma}

\begin{enumlemma}[(i)]{}
\item $f_{2n+1}=f_n^2+f_{n+1}^2$.
\item $f_{n+1}f_{n-1}-f_n^2=(-1)^n$.
\end{enumlemma}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Strange this doesn't work

Comment: What exactly does not work? Which kind of error message do you get? Did you add something else?

Comment: I find this fine, the only (possibly) problem is that it will cause slanted parentheses in the (i), (ii), etc

Comment: @leo: This depends on the theoremstyle. There won't be slanted parantheses for instance in environments based on the 'remark' style.

Comment: But it might be the case for example in the theorems you provided as example. That might be undesirable

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to write this down is without the word "case" which is implied in this notation. Just write

```
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item I found a soul mate
    \item never married
\end{enumerate}
```

inside your lemma.

Comment: The `enumerate` package is needed for this.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}`, ending with `\end{document}`. The required packages should be loaded.

Comment: Yes. I'll keep that in mind. Sorry.